# SQL: how to omitt "=", using only BETWEEN operator

Tags: mysql, sql

We have e.g. next table 'Persons':

```
Name    Salary    

Jack    500
Joe     1000
Nancy   550
Fiby    700
Max     1100
```

I want to select persons with salary between borders (500, 1000), using only 
BETWEEN operator, and selected salaries should be > 500, and < 1000. BETWEEN is shortage of >=, <=, so how to omitt that "="?

(yep, it can be solved e.g. with

```
SELECT * FROM Persons
WHERE Salary BETWEEN 500 and 1000
AND Salary NOT IN (500, 1000);
```

But just wondering - is it possible to do such selection with using Only BETWEEN (and 500, 1000 numbers).

Comment: Since you've not shown any decimals... `BETWEEN 501 AND 999`?

Comment: I noted "BETWEEN and 500, 1000 numbers"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **cant**. `BETWEEN` include border cases that is how work. Is like you ask a clock cook some pancakes, isn't what they are build for.

And you already have a workaround. Another would be:

```
 WHERE Salary > 500 and Salary < 1000
```

Comment: A clock can [make pancakes if you want it to](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KVdqwD_bcPs).

Answer (score 2):

If the datatype is `INT`, just adjust the range by 1.

```
WHERE salary BETWEEN 501 AND 999
```

Comment: I understand:), in question I noted, that only 500 and 1000 used.

Comment: Why such strict limitations? SQL doesn't have a "NOT INCLUSIVE" option to `BETWEEN`, you're going to have to adjust your requirements somehow.